# Test Card always approves not showing

Tags: android, testing, in-app-purchase

I'm trying to implement in app purchase to my Android app following [android.developers](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/integrate#java).

I've added items in Google Play Console --> Products --> In-App Products, my app is loading all of them but the problem is I'm not getting this [action](https://developer.android.com/images/google/play/billing/purchase-screen.png). I'm missing this part "Test card, always approves". It's loading my real credit card and not testing one like it was described [here](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/test)

Things that I've done:

- [Set up an internal test](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9845334?visit_id=637545493756942210-3734482693&rd=1#closed_beta&zippy=%2Cinternal-test-manage-up-to-testers)
- [Under "License Testing," added my testers' Gmail addresses](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6062777)
- Installed internal test app using link for beta testers ("You're an internal tester. This app may be unsecure or unstable"
- Testers have been added a day ago (if there is some period that should be waited for)

Did I miss something or what?

Any help would be precious. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: Encountering the same these days and I've done the same things as well.

Comment: I am facing the same issue but after 2 hour its show me test card

Comment: @AbdelrahmanSherif Google just need some time and it could take more (about a day or even more)

Comment: Having the same issue, have waited for over 48 hours, ensured test users were added as "Licensed Users", and still not seeing this option.